# Informatica passing values of a port to query in SQL transformation

Tags: sql, teradata, informatica

I have a SQL transformation with 2 ports. I want to insert the value of these ports to a table, however I am getting an error from sqlError port.

Below is the query I am writing in the source qualifier:

```
INSERT INTO A values (~QC_CODE~,(~QUERY_STRING~));
```

The `QUERY_STRING` port contains a sql statement which is executed on Teradata and results have to be inserted in the table A.

If I replace the first port in the above query with a constant value, I get correct results. Below is the query that gives correct result:

```
INSERT INTO A values ('1',(~QUERY_STRING~));
```

Comment: @JamesHunt Lets say that the port QC_CODE holds the value X, then the error is 'Column X not found in A. Unable to get Catalog String'.

Comment: I don't understand why is Informatica looking for Column X in the table, The Value X needs to be inserted in the first column.

Comment: Hmm, try to pre-place the quotes around the QC_CODE, as by the looks of the error it is just placing X instead of 'X' and erroring itself out.

Comment: @JamesHunt It wont work as putting single quotes will treat it as a string. I tried it as well, its not working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply BDW, I will keep looking. Will update it here if I get some workaround.

Comment: Maybe try to concat the quotes like: '''' || ~QC_CODE~ || ''''

Comment: Raj, I mean at the source where ~QC_CODE~ is set as X